# Calculating the number of possible password combinations given a set of constraints

Tags: combinatorics

There are several password combination problems on this site but none is exactly like mine: An $8$-character password contains 3 numbers, at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, and at least one special character. How many such password combinations are possible? (Note that, currently, there are $33$ publicly-known special characters in this world). Here's what I've been trying to do:
The three numbers will give us $10^3 = 1,000$ possible combinations. This now leaves us with $5$ characters that we have to account for. The sum of the pool of uppercase, lowercase and special characters is $26+26+33 = 85$. Thus, $85$ characters can fill $5$ slots in $85^5 = 4,437,053,125$ ways. However, this will not limit each uppercase, lowercase and special character to at least one, right? That is, my calculation also includes passwords like, say, 123abcde, right? I then tried $88^8 = 3,596,345,248,055,296$. The $88$ comes from the sum of $3$ numbers and the pool of $85$ characters we had earlier encountered. This also doesn't seem to work because, at the very least, the $3$ numbers are not specific.
How do I solve this?
Update: Here's what I tried next: In a table from one of the answers below, there are six major possibilities, so let's just work with one of them - a password containing $3$ numbers, $1$ uppercase, $1$ lowercase and $3$ special characters. Let's assume that the ordering is strictly that. That is, the first $3$ characters are numbers, the $4$th character is an uppercase, the $5$th character is lowercase, and the $6$th, $7$th and $8$th characters are special. Now, with this, how many such password combinations are possible? It's $220*26*26*33^3 = 5,344,550,640$. Yes, yes, yes, I know you're wondering where the $220$ comes from. These are all the triples where the first digit is less than or equal to the second digit AND the second digit is less than or equal to the third digit (I wrote a computer program to count them). We do this so that we can avoid duplicates. So far, this approach accounts for a password like, say, 123Aa+-* but ignores a password like 3Aa2+-*1. In order to account for it (and many others), we just permute. As such, our initial value of $5,344,550,640$ now gives us $5,344,550,640*8! = 215,492,281,804,800$ passwords. We do the same for the other $5$ major possibilities:
$3-1-2-2: 220*26*26^2*33^2*8!=169,781,797,785,600$
$3-1-3-1: 220*26*26^3*33*8!=133,767,477,043,200$
$3-2-1-2: 220*26^2*26*33^2*8!=169,781,797,785,600$
$3-2-2-1: 220*26^2*26^2*33*8!=133,767,477,043,200$
$3-3-1-1: 220*26^3*26*33*8!=133,767,477,043,200$
Adding it all up gives us: $956,358,308,505,600$

Comment: You need to be careful about arranging your sequences.  There are $220$ triples of nondecreasing numbers (the number of solutions of the equation $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 = 3$ in the nonnegative integers).  However, while the triple $(2, 3, 4)$ can be permuted in $3! = 6$ ways, the triple $(5, 5, 6)$ can only be permuted in $3$ ways and the triple $(7, 7, 7)$ can be permuted in one way.  More generally, if there are repetitions within the sequence, you cannot multiply by $8!$ since that counts sequences with repeated characters more than once.

Comment: My technique does not care whether the triple $(5,5,6)$ can only be permuted in $3$ ways. As an example, what it does is account for all $8$ character passwords where the first $3$ characters are $556$, the $4$th character is uppercase, the $5$th character is lowercase, and the last three characters are special. So a password like 556Aa+*-. The $8!$ then takes care of all possible arrangements of this password.

Comment: There are $\binom{8}{2}6!$ distinguishable permutations of $556Aa+*-$ (choose two positions for the $5$s, then arrange the remaining six distinct characters in the remaining six positions), not $8!$.  Therefore, you are over counting every permutation with a repeated character.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is only 8 characters in password, we could evaluate this directly.

First, you were right, since there is exactly 3 digits, there are $10^3$ ways to pick the digits. Then we have to choose the position of those digits: $8\choose 3$

For the remaining 5 characters, we need at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, and 1 special and two others to be determine.  This gives us 6 possible scenarii of Uppercase - Lowercase - Special :
$$1-1-3, 1-2-2, 1-3-1, 2-1-2, 2-2-1, 3-1-1$$
For the first scenario, the password has 3 digits, 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 3 special characters. We start by choosing the digits' positions, then we choose the digits (with replacement)
$${8\choose3}10^3$$
From the five remaining positions, we choose one for the uppercase, then choose the uppercase character
$${8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26$$
From the four remaining positions, we choose one for the lowercase, then choose the lowercase character
$${8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26{4\choose1}26$$
Finally, the three remaining positions are filled with special characters.
$${8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26{4\choose1}26{3\choose3}33^3$$

We do the same for each of the 6 possible scenarii.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Digits-Upper-Lower-Special} & \text{possibilities} \\
\hline
3-1-1-3 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26{4\choose1}26{3\choose3}33^3 \\
3-1-2-2 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26{4\choose2}26^2{2\choose2}33^2 \\
3-1-3-1 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose1}26{4\choose3}26^3{1\choose1}33 \\
3-2-1-2 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose2}26^2{3\choose1}26{2\choose2}33^2 \\
3-2-2-1 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose2}26^2{3\choose2}26^2{1\choose1}33 \\
3-3-1-1 & {8\choose3}10^3{5\choose3}26^3{2\choose1}26{1\choose1}33
\end{array}
$$

The numbers of possible passwords with these restrictions is $150\ 634\ 323\ 840\ 000$

Answer (score 2):

So, first you noticed correctly that $10$ digits and $10^3$ ways to pick three digits in sequence (*repetition allowed*) and that there are $85$ non-digit characters.

I assume that your passwords must contain *exactly* three digits.

Let us begin by answering the question of how many passwords there are with exactly $3$ digits with the available characterset where we *ignore* the requirement of having at least one upper, lower, and special characters.  We will take care of those additional requirements later.

To do this, choose where in the password the digits go in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways and then what they were in $10^3$ ways.  For the remaining positions, choose what characters they were in $85^5$ ways for a total of

$$\binom{8}{3}10^385^5$$

Now... among these some of them were "*invalid passwords*" for one or more reasons because of not having any lower case characters or not having any upper case characters, etc...  Let us count how many of the passwords were bad.  Once having done so we will subtract it from our total to have the count of how many of them were in fact good.

Counting those who didn't have any lower-case characters, we again pick where the digits went, what digits they were, and then for the $85-26=59$ non-lowercase characters remaining choose which character each remaining position is.  There are $\binom{8}{3}10^359^5$ such passwords that were bad because they had no lowercase characters.

Similarly, we can count how many were bad because they had no upper-case characters as well as how many were bad because they had no special characters.

Now... you might think that we just subtract those three numbers and then we're done... *BUT*... this doesn't take into account that some passwords were bad for multiple reasons.  We must correctly apply [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and after having subtracted these three numbers we must then *add back* what we subtracted too much of, namely the number of passwords that were bad for two reasons.  Note that no passwords exist that were bad for all three reasons simultaneously since otherwise we would have no available characters remaining to choose from, but in larger problems we might have needed to further correct our count and continued on to three, four, or more... alternating between adding and subtracting the counts.

Finish the problem by putting all of this together for a final answer.